# Always show service in notification bar

Tags: android, notifications, android-service

I want to add my app to the notification bar so that it always shows, like some apps in the Google Play store.

I want it to be like this screen shot:

[image]

I want my notification to not be cleared, and for my app to be opened when the notification is clicked.

**Here's My Service Class Code:**

```
package com.demo;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServiceExample extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Created",300).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service Destroy",300).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service LowMemory",300).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Service start",300).show();
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Rolling text on statusbar", System.currentTimeMillis());

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, ServiceDemoActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
                "Notification title", "Notification description", contentIntent);

        startForeground(1, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"task perform in service",300).show();
        /*ThreadDemo td=new ThreadDemo();
        td.start();*/
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Rolling text on statusbar", System.currentTimeMillis());

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, ServiceDemoActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
                "Notification title", "Notification description", contentIntent);

        startForeground(1, notification);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private class ThreadDemo extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            super.run();
            try{
            sleep(70*1000); 
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
   private Handler handler=new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        showAppNotification();
    }
   };

   void showAppNotification() {
       try{
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // The PendingIntent to launch our activity if the user selects this
        // notification.  Note the use of FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT so that, if there
        // is already an active matching pending intent, cancel it and replace
        // it with the new array of Intents.
//      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0,
//             "My service completed", PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        // The ticker text, this uses a formatted string so our message could be localized
        String tickerText ="djdjsdjkd";

        // construct the Notification object.
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, tickerText,
                System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Set the info for the views that show in the notification panel.
//      notif.setLatestEventInfo(this, from, message, contentIntent);

        // We'll have this notification do the default sound, vibration, and led.
        // Note that if you want any of these behaviors, you should always have
        // a preference for the user to turn them off.
        notif.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

        // Note that we use R.layout.incoming_message_panel as the ID for
        // the notification.  It could be any integer you want, but we use
        // the convention of using a resource id for a string related to
        // the notification.  It will always be a unique number within your
        // application.
        nm.notify(0, notif);
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.getMessage();
       }
    }
}
```

And I declare my Service in my project manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ServiceDemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".ServiceExample"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my class for starting and stopping the Service:

```
package com.demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class ServiceDemoActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.start).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private Intent inetnt;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.start:

            inetnt=new Intent(this,ServiceExample.class);
            startService(inetnt);
            break;
        case R.id.stop:

            inetnt=new Intent(this,ServiceExample.class);
            stopService(inetnt);
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
//      
    }
}
```

Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="StartService" 
        android:id="@+id/start"/>

        <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="StopService"
        android:id="@+id/stop" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want your application to be present on the status bar at all times, you have to write a service and call `startForeground(id, notification)` in the `onStart(...)` and `onStartCommand(...)` methods and respectively call the `stopForeground()` method in the `onDestroy()` method of the service.

The id is an integer you can assign to the notification and notification is a `Notification` object (you can read about it more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

This way as long as your service is running, the status bar notification will show.

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.statusbar_icon,
        "Rolling text on statusbar", System.currentTimeMillis());

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, YourActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(this,
        "Notification title", "Notification description", contentIntent);

startForeground(1, notification);
```

You can put this code in the service's `onStart(...)` and `onStartCommand(...)` methods.

Also you can read more on services here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: @paradx says error The method startForeground(int, Notification) is undefined

Comment: The startForeground(...) method is a member of the Service class. If you want to keep a notification on the status bar, you have to implement a service, you can't call it from an activity.

Comment: @paradx can u post service class code and how to register service?

Comment: @HeroVsZero This is not a bad answer, but I want to clarify that calling `startForeground()` is only appropriate if you really do need your Service to be in the foreground (e.g. a music player). @paradx is incorrect in thinking this has anything to do with having an ongoing notification. (Rather, the relationship is the inverse of that -- a notification is necessary in order to have your Service run in the foreground.)

Comment: I agree, but i don't think you would need an ongoing notification if you don't do any background work, hence my answer.If you really dont do anything in the background and still want a notification, you can use the same code to create the notification, but instead adding it with `startForeground()`, you could use the `NotificationManager` to put it on the statusbar in your `onCreate()` method and remove  it in your `onDestroy()` method.

Comment: @paradx "Doing background work" does not require your Service to run in the foreground, it's just a question of priority. Foreground Services are less likely to be killed when the system is running low on memory. Whether foreground or background, the Service can be killed at any time, and either way, it will be restarted when resources become available again. The only time you should call `startForeground()` is if the user would be very bothered to have a temporary disruption in the Service. I'd say you have it backwards -- most Services do *not* fall in that category.

Answer (score 20):

In order to have your notification always present, you'll want to set these two flags:

```
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

Note that while setting your Service to be in the foreground will also get you an ongoing event, that is a very inappropriate thing to do unless you truly do need your Service to run in the foreground.  A music player is a good example of an app that should do that -- the user  has an expectation that their music will play without interruption, even when doing many other things with the device.

Most Services, however, can afford to be temporarily stopped by the system when memory is low, and then restarted automatically when memory is available again.  So the correct way to think about it is to separate the two ideas.

1. If you want your notification to always be visible, use the two flags I mentioned.
2. If you happen to also need your Service to run in the foreground, you can and should call `Service.startForeground()`, but don't think of this as a way to get an ongoing notification.

Comment: @HeroVsZero You're very welcome. You might consider selecting this as the accepted answer, because, well, it's the right answer. As much as I'd love for paradx to keep the rep for his genuine and thoughtful answer, what he suggests is actually bad advice, as I've explained. I think steering future visitors to the most correct answer is the most important factor in deciding which answer to select.

Answer (score 2):

Just use below code to always show notification bar.

```
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentText("Call Recorder")
            .setAutoCancel(false);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR
            | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's example using NotificationCompact.Builder class which is the recent version to build notification.

```
private void startNotification() {

     //Sets an ID for the notification

  int mNotificationId = 001;

    // Build Notification , setOngoing keeps the notification always in status bar
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ldb)
                    .setContentTitle("Stop LDB")
                    .setContentText("Click to stop LDB")
                    .setOngoing(true);




    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Build the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());


}
```