# Keeping IRC connection active when application is closed

Tags: java, android

Trying to develop an irc app for android, and I haven't dabbled with service and such before, so just wondering if it would be feasible to create the object with the active irc connection in my activity, and then just send that object to a service when the app closes or pauses to maintain the connection in the background?

Would this be possible at all, or would the thread I create the connection on also be destroyed when the app closes?

Or should I just maintain the whole connection in the service?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a service maintain the connection by passing it the details before closing the activity in onPause or onDestroy. However it's not very advisable to have an ongoing connection in the background as this will drain the battery. You should look into having the service retrieve data within a repeating timer instead.

Comment: Hmm. Ok, that will be problematic for IRC :P

Comment: I disagree.  This use-case is one in which the user knows that the service is staying alive in order to keep that connection active.  As long as there is a notification in the notification bar that something is still active the application has done it's duty and it's up to the user to modulate their usage of the service.  Besides, the amount that the battery will be drained because an IRC connection is kept active pales in comparison to the amount the battery is drained keeping the screen or even cell reception active (assuming efficient implementation, of course).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a great use-case for keeping a notification active in the notification bar as can be seen in: [Always show service in notification bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292993/always-show-my-application-in-notification-bar).