# Shutting down app waze / moovit style

Tags: android, android-menu

I am looking for a way (a tutorial or something to read) to shut down my app like waze do i.e. After the app is running in the background once I'll slide the device notification menu down I can see my app running with a little "exit" button beneath it, once the button is pressed all the activities and services related to the app are closed and the application is terminated, someone have a lead or a good suggestion on how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after digging a little bit I found what is the proper way of doing it

Here are some detailed tutorials - 

[Always show service in notification bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292993/always-show-my-application-in-notification-bar)

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html