# How to stop service started from broadcastreceiver at user events

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

My background service starts at certain time using alarmmanager to play an audio track, and stops at completion of this track.
I want to enable user to stop the service when he expands notifications bar or any such user events (if it's impossible by notifications bar).

Code of receiver:

```
public class TimeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        context.startService(new Intent(context,TimeService.class));
    }
}
```

Code of service:

```
public class TimeService extends Service implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.hi);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        this.mediaPlayer.stop();
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can get idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292993/always-show-service-in-notification-bar

Answer (score 0):

1. Create Notification on start  and remove on stop.
2. Use PendingIntent to call on touch event on the notification (hint: you can use also Notification.Action).
3. Create a BroadcastReceiver to receive an action from PendingIntent.

   ```
   PendingIntent pi_my_action = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent( TimeService.MY_ACTION ), 0);

           Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                   .setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher )
                   .setContentTitle( title )
                   .setContentText( message )
                   .setContentIntent( pi_my_action );

   BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction().equals( TimeService.MY_ACTION )) {DoSomething();}}};
   ```